# Fastest way to validate MySQL against database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am using SqlAlchemy with MySql database in Python 3.4. I need to validate a SQL I receive through a PUT/POST call. What is the fastest way to check the correctness of the query? Right now I append `LIMIT 1` at the end and execute to check correctness. I need to do this before I accept the request. Sometimes the response time is increasing to `~750ms` from `~50ms`. Is there a better method than what I am doing?

```
def validate_sql(self, sql: str):
    adapter_logger.debug('Validating query %r', sql)

    conn = cursor = None
    try:
        conn = self._engine.raw_connection()
        cursor = conn.cursor(Cursor)
        cursor.execute('{0} LIMIT 1'.format(sql))
    except (MySQLError, SQLAlchemyError) as e:
        msg = 'Invalid sql - {0!r}. Cause: {1}'.format(sql, e)
        adapter_logger.exception(msg)
        raise errors.DatabaseClientError(msg)
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
        if conn:
            conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way to check validity of a query should be using [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html), which will check the execution plan of the query without executing it.

In your case you may want to check that the query starts with `SELECT` first so that the string does not start with any of the parameters that can be used with `EXPLAIN`.

```
> CREATE TABLE test (id INT);
> EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM testd;   # invalid query
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'test.testd' doesn't exist
> EXPLAIN SELECT id2 FROM test;   # invalid query
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'id2' in 'field list'
> EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM test;    # valid query
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra |
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to observe an improvement in speed.